# How can I concatenate N lists and sum the N elements of a list of lists in Python?

Tags: python

I'm currently building a pricing model for irrigation.
The code below gives a price for a single selection or multiple selections.
After the selection(s) have been made there is an input in which it is possible to specify the quantity of the previous selection(s).

```
class Text:

    def __init__(self):
        pass

    labor = "Labor Cost: $"
    parts = "Parts Cost: $"
    pre_total = "Zone Subtotal: $"
    total = "Zone Total: $"
    error = "Invalid"
    zones = "Information for Zone: "
    annotations = "Notes for Zone: "
    controller = "For Controller:"
    total_labor = "Labor Total: $"
    total_parts = "Parts Cost: $"
    zone_total = "Zone total: $"
    time = strftime("%Y-%m-%d", gmtime())


class ActivityTime:
    def __init__(self):
        pass

    StraightenHeads = 0.33
    Raise_Lower_Heads = 0.33
    Replace_Add_Riser = 0.25
    Replace_Bubbler = 0.25
    Replace_Nozzle = 0.15
    Replace_SprayHead = 0.35
    Replace_RotorHead = 0.35
    Replace_Solenoid = 0.25
    Replace_Valve = 0.5


class PartsPrice:
    def __init__(self):
        pass

    StraightenHeads = 0.0
    Raise_Lower_Heads = 0.0
    Replace_Add_Riser = 7.50
    Replace_Bubbler = 7.50
    Replace_Nozzle = 2.50
    Replace_SprayHead = 7.50
    Replace_RotorHead = 20.00
    Replace_Solenoid = 87.50
    Replace_Valve = 87.50


class Labor:
    def __init__(self):
        pass

    cost = 125


selections = ["Straighten or Raise / Lower Heads",
              "Replace/Add Riser",
              "Bubbler ",
              "Nozzle",
              "Spray Head",
              "Rotor Head ",
              "Solenoid",
              "Valve",
              "No REPLACEMENT"]


def y_input():
    input_y = list(map(int, input().split()))
    return input_y


class Selection:

    def __init__(self):
        pass

    @staticmethod
    def options():
        x1 = list(map(int, input('''
            1. Straighten or Raise/Lower Heads  \n
            2. Replace or Add Riser             \n
            3. Replace Bubbler                  \n
            4. Replace Nozzle                   \n
            5. Replace Spray Head               \n
            6. Replace Rotor Head               \n
            7. Replace Solenoid                 \n
            8. Replace Valve                    \n
            9. No REPLACEMENT

            Select number for replacement:
            ''').split()))

        """"""

        if x1 == 9:
            return x1
        elif x1 != 9:
            print('''
            Number of Replacement Parts For ''')
            for i, item in enumerate(selections):
                for x in x1:
                    if x == i + 1:
                        print('''
                %s  ''' % item)
            y2 = y_input()
            return pre_total(x1, y2)


class Cost:
    discount = 0.0

    def __init__(self, x, y):
        self.x = x
        self.y = y

    def parts(self):
        while True:
            if self.x == 1 and self.y == self.y:
                parts_charge = PartsPrice.StraightenHeads * self.y
                return parts_charge
            elif self.x == 2 and self.y == self.y:
                parts_charge = PartsPrice.Raise_Lower_Heads * self.y
                return parts_charge
            elif self.x == 3 and self.y == self.y:
                parts_charge = PartsPrice.Replace_Add_Riser * self.y
                return parts_charge
            elif self.x == 4 and self.y == self.y:
                parts_charge = PartsPrice.Replace_Nozzle * self.y
                return parts_charge
            elif self.x == 5 and self.y == self.y:
                parts_charge = PartsPrice.Replace_SprayHead * self.y
                return parts_charge
            elif self.x == 6 and self.y == self.y:
                parts_charge = PartsPrice.Replace_RotorHead * self.y
                return parts_charge
            elif self.x == 7 and self.y == self.y:
                parts_charge = PartsPrice.Replace_Solenoid * self.y
                return parts_charge
            elif self.x == 8 and self.y == self.y:
                parts_charge = PartsPrice.Replace_Valve * self.y
                return parts_charge
            else:
                return Text.error

    def labor(self):
        if self.x == 1 and self.y == self.y:
            total_labor = (ActivityTime.StraightenHeads * Labor.cost) * self.y
            return total_labor
        elif self.x == 2 and self.y == self.y:
            total_labor = (ActivityTime.Raise_Lower_Heads * Labor.cost) * self.y
            return total_labor
        elif self.x == 3 and self.y == self.y:
            total_labor = (ActivityTime.Replace_Add_Riser * Labor.cost) * self.y
            return total_labor
        elif self.x == 4 and self.y == self.y:
            total_labor = (ActivityTime.Replace_Nozzle * Labor.cost) * self.y
            return total_labor
        elif self.x == 5 and self.y == self.y:
            total_labor = (ActivityTime.Replace_SprayHead * Labor.cost) * self.y
            return total_labor
        elif self.x == 6 and self.y == self.y:
            total_labor = (ActivityTime.Replace_RotorHead * Labor.cost) * self.y
            return total_labor
        elif self.x == 7 and self.y == self.y:
            total_labor = (ActivityTime.Replace_Solenoid * Labor.cost) * self.y
            return total_labor
        elif self.x == 8 and self.y == self.y:
            total_labor = (ActivityTime.Replace_Valve * Labor.cost) * self.y
            return total_labor
        else:
            return Text.error

    def subtotal(self):
        a = Cost.labor(self)
        b = Cost.parts(self)
        a + b
        # return a, b
        return [a, b, a+b]


def pre_total(x1, y2):
    if len(x1) == 1:
        for x, item2 in enumerate(x1):
            for y, item3 in enumerate(y2):
                pre = Cost(item2, item3)
                pre_total_list1 = list(pre.subtotal())
                for i, item in enumerate(selections):
                    if x == y and item2 == i + 1:
                        print(item3, item, pre_total_list1)
    elif len(x1) > 1:
        for x, item2 in enumerate(x1):
            for y, item3 in enumerate(y2):
                pre = Cost(item2, item3)
                pre_total_list2 = list(pre.subtotal())
                for i, item in enumerate(selections):
                    if x == y and item2 == i + 1:
                        # print(item3, item, pre_total_list2)
                        zone_total(item3, item, pre_total_list2)
    else:
        return
    
def zone_total(x1, y2, z):
    print(x1, y2)
    pre_list = [0,0,0]
    final_list = [sum(i) for i in zip(pre_list, z)]
    print(final_list)

a = Selection
a.options()
```

if two selections (7,8) and (2,2) are provided this will print out (example):

```
2 Solenoid
[62.5, 175.0, 237.5]
2 Valve
[125.0, 175.0, 300.0]
```

How can I make it so that it prints out N lists + the sum of all N lists no matter the inputs? Like this:

```
2 Solenoid
[62.5, 175, 237.50]
2 Valve
[125, 175, 300.00]
Total:
[187.5, 350, 537.50]
```

I tried using:

```
def sum_elements(lstlst):
    return [sum(tup) for tup in zip(*lstlst)]

def main(lstlst):
    print(*lstlst, sum_elements(lstlst), sep="\n")
```

With this code I get float not iterable error:

```
   return [sum(tup) for tup in zip(*lstlst)]
TypeError: 'float' object is not iterable
```

I understand that I'm getting this error because I'm applying lstlst to a list of things.
My problem (I assume) is that I'm  not concatenating the N lists before applying the lstlst function?

Comment: What is `lstlst`? I am sure that most of the code you provided above is not really relevant. Please work out a [mre] of your code

Answer (score 1):

```
from itertools import zip_longest


def sum_elements(*lsts):
    return [sum(tup) for tup in zip_longest(*lsts, fillvalue=0)]


def main():
    l1 = [62.5, 175, 237.50]
    l2 = [125.0, 175.0, 300.0]
    l3 = [12.0, 165.0, 300.0, 12]

    print(sum_elements(l1, l2, l3))


if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

**Test:**

```
$ python test.py
[199.5, 515.0, 837.5, 12]
```